# storing chatlog on azure sql database in bot framework v4 with C#

Tags: c#, botframework

I am developing bot using bot framework V4 with C#. In order to store chatlog history in database, I implemented ITranscriptLogger as shown below.

```
public class ActivityLogger :ITranscriptLogger
    {
        public ActivityLogger()
        {
            //do something
        }
        public async Task LogActivityAsync(IActivity activity)
        {
            await UpdateLog();
        }
        
        public Task UpdateLog()
        {
           //store log in sql database
        }
    }
```

In startup.cs , I have added following code

```
var logger = new ActivityLogger();
  var transcriptMiddleware = new TranscriptLoggerMiddleware(logger);
 services.AddSingleton<TranscriptLoggerMiddleware>(transcriptMiddleware);
```

I am expecting LogActivityAsync to be called during each conversation..but this is not getting called.
hence I am not able to store conversation history in database.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is your question? Please have a look at the handy guide to see the steps you can take to get a better answer faster: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you still working on this?